# How to connect to a Bitnami Redis Cluster from another host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, bitnami, redis-cluster

I have a configuration in my docker-compose.yml file, and I'm using Bitnami. Everything runs correctly, and the cluster is created successfully. I have a Java application where I use Jedis to connect to the Redis cluster. When I connect to the cluster from the same host as the app, it works fine. However, when I try to run the app from another host (**on the same network**) pointing to the same Redis cluster, it fails to connect. It's important to mention that I can connect perfectly to any of the cluster nodes' CLI from the other host. But when I attempt to connect from the app or even from DataGrip, I get an error; it's simply impossible for me to establish a connection. I've tried various configurations, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to resolve it. Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:   redis-node-0:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.2
    ports:
      - '6385:6379'
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
      - 'REDIS_BIND=192.168.100.12'

  redis-node-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.2
    ports:
      - '6380:6379'
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
      - 'REDIS_BIND=192.168.100.12'

  redis-node-2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.2
    ports:
      - '6381:6379'
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
      - 'REDIS_BIND=192.168.100.12'

  redis-node-3:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.2
    ports:
      - '6382:6379'
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
      - 'REDIS_BIND=192.168.100.12'

  redis-node-4:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.2
    ports:
      - '6383:6379'
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
      - 'REDIS_BIND=192.168.100.12'

  redis-node-5:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.2
    ports:
      - '6384:6379'
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_REPLICAS=1'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_CREATOR=yes'
      - 'REDIS_BIND=192.168.100.12'

volumes:   redis-cluster_data-0:
    driver: local   redis-cluster_data-1:
    driver: local   redis-cluster_data-2:
    driver: local   redis-cluster_data-3:
    driver: local   redis-cluster_data-4:
    driver: local   redis-cluster_data-5:
    driver: local`
```

Now, this is what I get when I run 'docker ps' from the terminal:
[Docker images cluster nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RucGk.png)

I need help overcoming this issue

– how to connect to a Bitnami Redis cluster from another host.

**I would expect to be able to connect to the Bitnami Redis cluster from any other host** within the same network. However, when attempting to connect from another host, the app displays the following exception:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisClusterOperationException: Cluster retry deadline exceeded.
    at redis.clients.jedis.executors.ClusterCommandExecutor.executeCommand(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:124) ~[jedis-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.UnifiedJedis.executeCommand(UnifiedJedis.java:244) ~[jedis-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.UnifiedJedis.llen(UnifiedJedis.java:1074) ~[jedis-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.paic.insertdata.component.Worker.smResponseWorker(Worker.java:125) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Did you find out?

Comment: I still do not know